# How to send an email on windows 8 metro app?

Tags: email, windows-8

The namespace System.Net.Mail is not used on windows 8 metro apps correct ?
How do I set an app to send emails ?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, check out [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winappswithcsharp/thread/393a123f-674c-4b44-af87-9963053f42fd) and [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/3d80b028-96a0-4347-b542-22058dc25b42).

If you want to send emails from your app I suggest you set up a server which can receive requests from the app and send emails from that :)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 8 apps you can launch a URI that starts with `mailto:`. You can set the email address, subject, and body as well by adding parameters to the URI.  Here is an example:

```
var mailto = new Uri("mailto:?to=name@email.com&subject=Here is a subject&body=Message here.");
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```